# Unable to pass parameter to XGBoost

Tags: python, machine-learning, parameter-passing, xgboost, grid-search

I'm attempting to grid search on several parameter give my dataset.
I noticed the paramters I'm passing to my `xgboost` function is not being received. For instance the output of my model is `alg.get_params()`
is

```
{'colsample_bytree': 1,  'gamma': 0,  'learning_rate': 0.1,  'max_depth': 3, 'n_estimators': 100, 'objective': 'multi:softmax', 'reg_alpha': 0,  'reg_lambda': 1}
```

I've defined a simple dictionary for the parameters as follows:

```
xgb_params = {
        'maxdepth':[8],
        'objective':['multi:softmax'],
        'n_estimators':[600, 900, 1200],
        'gamma':[0, .1, .2],
        'lambda':[.5, 1, 3],
        'alpha':[.5, 1, 2],
        'num_class':[3],
        #Other parameters
             }
```

The actual pass of the parameters are handled through a `gridsearch` function as below:

```
alg = XGBClassifier()
grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator = alg, param_grid=xgb_params, scoring='accuracy', cv=4, verbose=1)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong. After doing some research, many authors suggest using `hyperopt` for an optimized search/tune of hyperparamters, however I'm trying to understand where I'm going wrong with my current approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is fine with your code, you're just looking at the wrong thing. `alg.get_params()` presents you the default parameters of the estimator, while via `GridSearchCV` you train `4` models. To access them, you need to query `grid_search` like this:

To get all results:

```
print(grid_search.cv_results_)
```

Your best estimator:

```
print(grid_search.best_estimator_)
```

And its hyperparameters:

```
print(grid_search.best_params_)
```